# Windows Application-How to compile .rc files and source files all together

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, windows

Ok. I have a .rc file and resource.h and and my source file. But I don't know how to compile them all together. I have compilers- Visual Studio Express 2013, Dev C++, and MinGW.
This is my first time making windows applications and I have no idea how I compile rc files and my resource.h file along with my source file. 
I want some help on this.

I tried it in Visual Studio because it was well organized, but it doesn't support resources. And I have no idea what to do in Dev C++ and MinGW is best for me, but I don't know where to put my .rc file and my header.

Comment: Visual Studio absolutely does support (Windows) resource files. In fact, it should compile resource files automatically if they are present in your project. The compilation for resource files is done by a separate program called the [resource compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381042.aspx), which is present in both Visual Studio and the Windows SDK if I recall correctly.

Comment: I said Visual Studio Express, not Visual Studio. Visual Studio Express doesn't support resource files.

Comment: Does the resource compiler available in Visual Studio Express, too?

Comment: Visual Studio Express can't *edit* resource files, but there's nothing preventing you from invoking the resource compiler `rc.exe` itself from Visual Studio. IIRC the Windows SDK comes with a resource compiler, but don't quote me on that.